# Jquery parsing response from api bbyopen

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, curl

I am having trouble parsing from this api. Can you see what I have done?

The PHP Curl Call:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(salePrice<='.$dollars.'&type=Music)?apiKey=gzunxsecretsdssf444&format=json&show=name,salePrice,shortDescription,image',
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
                );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

The js:

```
$.ajax({
           url: "./file.php",
           type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
           success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
                console.log(data);
                for(var i=0;i<=data.products.length;i++)
                {
                    var thumb=data.products[i].image;
                    $('<div class="product" style="background-color:green"><a href=""><img src="'+ thumb +'" alt""/></a></div>').appendTo('#find_stuff_div');
                }
            }
           });
```

var thumb=data.products[i].image; is where I am having trouble. The object itself logs (apparently as json) but var thumb returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined ". Any ideas?

Console log
[image: console]

Comment: what is `data.products` is it an array

Comment: also add a `console.log(data.products, data.products.length)`

Comment: I added the results from the console above

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `JSON.parse()` on the returned data in order to use it as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your for loop is wrong

```
for(var i=0;i<data.products.length;i++)
```

The array index start from `0` to `length - 1`, so your condition should be `i<data.products.length` not `i<=data.products.length`

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with var thumb=data.products[i].image; not having a value though.

Comment: yes, when the value of `i` becomes `data.products.length` ie 10, `data.products[10]` is undefined, because data.products has indexes 0..9 not 0..10